# html javascript jquery select click the option and load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load the option value in div>. The below code can be run successfully.

```
 <select onchange="location.assign = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option>Please select</option>
    <option value="page1.html">page1</option>
    <option value="page2.html">page2</option>
    <option value="page3.html">page3</option>
</select>​
<div id="load_page"></div>
```

How can I load the page inside div
thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: updated the question. thanks

Comment: Upload the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery you can use $.load():

```js
$(function() {
  var page = $('#load_page');
  $('#pages').on('change', function(e) {
    var option = $(this).find('option:selected');
    if (0 === option.index()) {
      page.text('Oops');
    } else {

      page.text('Loading ' + option.val());
      page.load(option.val());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pages">
  <option>Please select</option>
  <option value="page1.html">page1</option>
  <option value="page2.html">page2</option>
  <option value="page3.html">page3</option>
</select>
<div id="load_page"></div>
```

With just iframe and js:

```js
document.getElementById('pages').onchange = function(e) {
  document.getElementById('load_page').src = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
};
```

```html
<select id="pages">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="page1.html">page1</option>
  <option value="page2.html">page2</option>
  <option value="page3.html">page3</option>
</select>
<iframe id="load_page"></iframe>
```

Comment: This works! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method of jquery. The load() method loads data from a server and puts the returned data into the selected element.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("select").on("change", function() {
        if($("select option:selected").index() > 0) {
            console.log("cannot load");
        } else {
            $("#load_page").load($('option').val());
        }
    });
});
```